# How to access AngularJS Directive attributes when inside & outside an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Have the following attribute directive.

```
angular.module('app.directives.auctionItemCard', [])
        .directive('auctionItemCard', function() {
        return {
            restict: 'A',
            scope: {
                auctionItem: '=',
                actionWatch:'&'
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/auctionTangoApp/template/itemTemplate.html',
            link:function(scope, element,attrs) {
                console.log(scope.auctionItem);
            },
            controller: function ($scope) {

                    console.log($scope.auctionItem);

                }
            };
        });
```

With the following HTML markup in one view called items.html

```
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="item in items">

        <div auction-item-card data-auction-item="item" ></div>

    </div>
```

And the following HTML markup in just a view called itemDetails.html

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div  auction-item-card data-auction-item="item"></div>
    </div>
```

When the directive is inside the ng-repeat it works perfectly fine.
However when the directive is outside and the view's controller sets the item value inside the directive the $scope.auctionItem is always undefined.

Can someone please shed some light on the difference between when a directive is outside an ng-repeater?

To add clarity here is the items view's controller:

```
var auctionItemsController = function ($scope, $location, $filter, $window,
        $timeout, $routeParams, authService, auctionService, categoryService, productService) {
        var auctionId = ($routeParams.auctionId) ? parseInt($routeParams.auctionId) : 0, timer;

        $scope.items = [];

        function init() {
                getItems();
        }


        function getItems()
        {
            productService.getProducts(auctionId, $scope.pageIndex, $scope.itemsPerPage).then(function (data) {
                $scope.items = data.results;

            });
        }

        init();

    };
```

Here is the item details controller:

```
var itemController = function ($scope, $routeParams,$location, $filter, $window,
        $timeout, authService, productService) {

        var itemId = ($routeParams.itemid) ? parseInt($routeParams.itemid) : 0;


        function init() {
           // $scope.item = {};
            productService.getProductById(itemId).then(function(item) {
                $scope.item = item;
            });
        };
        init();
    };
```

Comment: `item` only exists within the `ng-repeat` - are you trying to show details after a click or something?

Comment: Darren I added the controller code

Comment: Can you verify you're actually getting an item back in your service call? perhaps a console.log(item) -

Comment: Yes item is actually comeing back.  The view renders but inside the directive controller the auctionItem is always undefined when not nested in a ng-repeat

Comment: Also - have you tried changing the name of `$scope.item` in your `itemController` to something else; just incase it's a scope inheritance issue.?

Comment: On a side-note - you don't need to wrap your service calls in an `init()` function as they're running async and returning a promise.

Comment: I just do that to keep my code clean in terms of what needs to run first.  I did change the the name and still the same result.

Comment: It's unnecessary though, the `init()` i mean. Because of all the two-way binding Angular does by design, then you're not going to run into issues where some object isn't there yet because your service hasn't run etc. You can safely remove it and it will not break :) - as for your actual issue.. hard to say to be honest. Code looks ok, other than the function calls.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, `item` is undefined.  It is only defined in your ng-repeat (`item in items`).

Comment: the second example the item is defined in the view's controller, not to be confused with directives controller.

Comment: Ok, you didn't mention that.  Can you post your controller and the full markup that isn't working?

Comment: Just did.  I think I might have to add an observe on the attribute?

Comment: You shouldn't need the observe as you're defining 2-way binding in your directive.

Answer (score 0):

O.k. here is the issue.  When the directive is inside ng-repeat by the time the controller function has been called angular has already done the binding and so the $scope variable is set.  When outside of ng-repeat that has not taken place and so any attempted to access the scope variables defined on the attribute may return an undefined since my variable was inside aync call.

The solution to getting access to my imageUrl of my auction item was modify the function the ng-style was calling to this:

```
$scope.auctionItemImage = function(url)
                {

                    return {
                        background: 'url(' + url + ')',
                        width: '100px',
                        height: '100px',
                        backgroundSize: 'cover',
                        margin: '0 auto'
                }
                };
```

then in my template modify this line:

to this:

I hope this helps anyone else who wants to use their directive in various scenarios.